# WordPress Divi: Text Option in Content Tab in Row Settings has disappeared

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've just encountered a problem where my text option disappeared from under the content tab in row settings. Well, technically I tried changing a few things and removed it accidentally. I tried canceling, reverting the changes but nothing worked. There has to be a way to bring it back so I can see the text and its visual impact on the page.

Below I put a screenshot with marked fields. Text option was previously above the Link Option. How can I restore it?

[image]

Comment: As we don't know what you have changed, it's going to be difficult for people to help. Can't you just restore it to your latest backup? or restore your backup to a separate instance and have a look at that?

Comment: Well, I had probably right clicked the option and created a title page. Then I wanted to discard the change and somehow removed the whole 'Text Option' with no way to revert it back. I thought the problem was present only on my prototype page, where the modification has been made. Unluckily, it is worse than that. Somehow it propagated over every other module on the entire website... Seriously? Is there no way to 'repair' it without resorting to drastic measures like website back up?

Comment: I don't know, I am not a Wordpress SME, but surely this sort of situation is exactly what backups are usually for? I don't see them as particularly drastic measures, assuming you can restore code and/or  content components selectively.

Comment: @MandyShaw All right, thanks for your time and advice. If somehow I figure it out I will update the question with a solution.